# Where is it better to implement Copy/Cut/Paste in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a project using `C#/WPF` and following `MVVM` pattern. This project is designed for touch screens.

The major objects of the program are the following:

We have `Programs` which contain `Channels` which contain `Functions`. All these should be able to be copied/cut/pasted.

I have to implement a copy/cut/paste functionnalities and wonder where it is best.

My idea was to implement them in the ViewModel because it seems to me bizarre to have such functionnalities in the Models.

However as Models should contain the full Business logic it would be logical to implement them here but I have a doubt.

What is the best practice for such an implementation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you going to use the clipboard or a custom cut/paste where you store the items in an array or something?

Comment: I am going to use a custom cut/paste stored in a `List<>` of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a clipboard service

```
IClipboard
{
    void AddProgram(Program p);
    Program GetProgram(string id);
    ..... etc
}
```

and inject this into the ViewModel, which would have the copy paste commands bound to your copy/paste keystrokes or whatever

```
ViewModel
{
    void OnCopy() {
        if(mouseIsOverAProgram) { this.clip.AddProgram(getProgramUnderMouse())
    }
}
```

Your Models are Program, Channels, Functions etc and shouldn't know about this kind of logic.